# Intercom track event send an auto message automatically

Tags: intercom

How do I send an auto message, every time an event occurs, automatically. Event occurs, send auto message immediately? Right now, it takes a while for the message to show when we track an event

Answer (score 1):

These should clear this up, I was asking the same question just last week :D

https://docs.intercom.com/faqs-and-troubleshooting/sending-messages/when-do-email-auto-messages-send

https://docs.intercom.com/faqs-and-troubleshooting/sending-messages/why-hasnt-a-user-received-my-message

## to summarise:

> There are a few different times that your email auto messages will be matched and sent to your users. We'll look at each in turn:
>
> - **When you first put your message live:** As soon as you set your message live we will immediately check for matching users and queue messages to be sent.
> - **Once each hour:** In the case that your user hasn't logged in (or had their data otherwise updated) we check once each hour to see if there are any messages that now match that user. Time based messages frequently are sent under this condition.
> - **Only during times that you set.** You can set delivery window for your emails to be sent.
> - **When the messenger loads** or a call to Intercom('update’) is complete.

Thanks to the guys & gals of Intercom for their helpful help articles.

Comment: Not loving that down vote :(
Care to add a reason or actual answer?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for coming late to the party, but hope this helps someone.

An automessage is just sent once, when a configurable criteria is met. This message is then shown in the messenger - as a popup - when:

1. The messenger is loaded
2. When `window.Intercom('update');` has been issued

If you're already tracking events in Intercom from your app like `window.Intercom('trackEvent', '<your event>');`, an option is to add a webhook in your backend that Intercom can call when a given tracking event happens. This webhook can then in turn call Intercom's rest api to start a conversation with the customer.

This is documented here:

- [Track event webhook](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#topics%20%22%22)
- [Admin intiated conversation](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#admin-initiated-conversation)

Or if you only want to send a message (to start a conversation), just omit the tracking event piece and create an admin initiated conversation by posting to https://api.intercom.io/messages with a payload

> ```
> {
>   "message_type": "inapp",
>   "body": "This is a message started from the backend",
>   "from": {
>     "id": "<admin id>",
>     "type": "admin"
>   },
>   "to": {
>     "email": "<email>",
>     "type": "User"
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with Intercom and Zapier, when you are using the Intercom API to trigger an automated admin initiated message via the Zapier webhook. You only need to POST to https://api.intercom.io/messages along with JSON message. This POST can be done with the Zapier webhook. Now you only need to define a trigger, which also can be done via Zapier. This can either be an event or some other data you want to send this for.

This is the POST you need to send to Intercom:

```
$ curl https://api.intercom.io/messages \
-XPOST \
-H 'Authorization:Bearer <YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "message_type": "email",
  "subject": "Hey",
  "body": "Ponies, cute small horses or something more sinister?",
  "template": "plain",
  "from": {
    "type": "admin",
    "id": "YOUR_ID"
  },
  "to": {
    "type": "user",
    "email": "YOUR_USER_EMAIL"
  }
}'
```

**[The exact steps are documented here](https://medium.com/generato/instant-emails-with-intercom-and-zapier-webhooks-92ab1a269004)**